# Why doesn't my multithreaded code run faster on EC2 AWS?

Tags: multithreading, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, concurrency

So I've implemented a code that creates 8 threads in c++ using a simple

array of threads using lambda functions .... then joining them after they are done.

On my laptop, it takes about 10 minutes (without threads, it would take about 100 minutes)

But when I use run the same codes on AWS' EC2 C5 Extra Large, the code actually takes much longer to compute.

Is concurrency possible for EC2? does it need to be modified in some way?

```
    class concurr{
    public:

    double arr[8];
    void func1(vector<vector<double>> data,int x);
    double func2(vector<vector<double>> data);
    }
```

these would be the types of functions I would be dealing with

```
    double concurr::func2(vector<vector<double>> data){

        thread threads[8];
        for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++){
            threads[x] = thread( [&]{ this->func1(data, x); } );
        }
        for (auto& th : threads){
            th.join();
        }
        // ..... does something with the arr[8].... to come up with double = value
        return value;
    }
```

this is the general outline of the code. so func1 will take in "data" and varying values of "x" and comes up with some values and stores them in arr[x]

Comment: what is your code actually doing? Of course creating 8 threads takes more time than creating a single one

Comment: I've checked the CPU utilization, and initially it goes to 100%, but later on, keeps dropping until 0% while nothing's actually being computed

Comment: each thread performs cross-validation of a given data set, for a given hyperparameter (total of 8 different hyperparameter set) Not too computationally expensive tho.

Comment: Multi-threading works on EC2 as anywhere else (given the code is correct).  Could you validate the lambdas are really executed in parallel? Don't you need any specific glib/c++ library?

Comment: C5.xlarge has 8 gigs of ram and 4 virtual cpus - there is no guarantee it is as performant as your laptop, especially if you've done no optimisations for the environment it's running in.  If your datasets are large your C5.xlarge could be paging to swap.

Comment: *"the code actually takes much longer to compute"*  Longer than 10 minutes, or longer than 100?  How many cores and hyperthreads does your laptop have?